# Android Http Wrapper

Tags: android, facebook, http, wrapper, facebook-sdk-3.0

I need to write a simple **HTTP wrapper** for working with **Facebook SDK** on android.

I'm very new to Android and I'm trying to use tutorials but everything I find is based on **HttpClient** that is `already deprecated` and I don't want to start working with Android with deprecated functionality.

So my question is what is the best practice right now for HTTP wrapper ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what I did is followed facebook documentation deeper and find out that I can use GraphRequest to work with facebook SDK.

for example getting facebook friends list will be like this:

```
    public void getFriendsList(AccessToken acccess_token) throws Exception {
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMyFriendsRequest(acccess_token,new GraphRequest.GraphJSONArrayCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONArray objects, GraphResponse response) {
            Type collectionType = new TypeToken<FaceBookProfile>(){}.getType();
            FaceBookProfile profile = GsonUtils.createGson().fromJson(response.getRawResponse(), collectionType);
        }
    }) ;
    request.executeAsync();
}
```

I also aded GSON library to be able to drectlly parse JSON objects

you can do it by adding this code to dependances :

```
dependencies {
```

compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
}

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel unless you must.

[Volley is a great library](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) to use.

> Volley is an HTTP library that makes networking for Android apps
>   easier and most importantly, faster. Volley is available through the
>   open AOSP repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to [DefaultHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) then all the libraries that you could use are wrappers around it.The other option is [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) which is the choice of the Android framework.

You could always use a third party library like [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) or [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html).They would take care of backward compatibility too ,(HttpURLConenction is not available prior API 11).

If you are planning to build skeletal wrappers specific to your use,then HttpURLConnection is an appropriate choice.As for best practices , what applies to DefaultHttpConnection continues to apply here.

Comment: can you please give me an example of HttpURLConnection - working with facebook Graph API ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Square's Retrofit library for your network operations.
http://square.github.io/retrofit/

You should create a response interceptor class like below.

```
public class YourWrapper implements Interceptor {
   @Override
   public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
      Request request = chain.request();
      Response response = chain.proceed(request);
      // After you get response you can do what ever you want.
      // If you need you can re call same api with return     chain.proceed(newRequest);
   }
}
```

You can set your custom response interceptor class to Rest Api like below:

```
          OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
          client.interceptors().add(new YourWrapper());
          RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.BASIC)
                                                             .setClient(new OkClient(client))
                                                             .setEndpoint(url).build();
```

After you set your wrapper response interceptor to your rest api, when you get an api result first your wrapper will catch response and than your callbacks'll catch response.